# Insert values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I am trying to insert into a field using the input from another table field. Although this is entirely feasible for many database engine,

I have the following fields,

**New Table Schema**

- Name
- Industryid(int)
- Locationid(int)

But the actual records like,

- xxxx
- TEXT (varchar)
- TEXT(Varchar)

But I want these two Industryid and Locationid by id's from another table Industries, Locations.

I have another 2 tables for

**Industries**

- Id
- Name

**Locations**

- Id
- Name

**My Query is,**

```
select'insert into organizations(name,industryid,locationid)
values
('''+
Nameofthecompany+''','+
Isnull(industrytype,'Null')+','+
ISNULL(Location,'Null')+')' 
from Organization`
```

**Result**

```
insert into organizations(name,industryid,locationid) 
values 
('Swamy',Telcom,Chennai)
```

**Expected Result**

```
insert into organizations(name,industryid,locationid)
values
('Swamy',12,150)
```

Comment: table structure??? insert query??? please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current/actual records are already in a table named `Organization` as shown in your query, you can use this approach to populate your new `Organizations` table:

```
INSERT INTO Organizations( name, IndustryId, LocationId )
SELECT o.Nameofthecompany, i.Id, l.Id
FROM Organization AS o
LEFT JOIN Industries AS i ON o.industrytype = i.Name
LEFT JOIN Location AS l ON o.Location = l.Name
```

This takes the existing names, joins to your reference tables (`Industries` and `Locations`) and retrieves the `Id` values for the corresponding text values.

The `LEFT JOIN` will bring back all of the names from Organization, but not require them to have a matching Industry and Location in the reference tables.

Comment: I am getting no changes there when i execute this one. why?

Comment: I used instead of inner join to left join. then it is working.

Comment: @AngDei I have updated my answer to have the LEFT JOIN.  This removes the requirement to have industrytype and Location match a value in your reference table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
INTO TestTable
FROM OriginalTable
WHERE Conditions
```

*Notice that SELECT INTO only works if the table specified in the INTO clause does not exist*

Or:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Col1, Col2)
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM OriginalTable
WHERE Conditions
```